# sed - replace currently assigned value to a variable with user input in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to update an assigned variable value in a file but it is not working.

e.g. currently the assigned value is: sga_target=3GB,  <<--Need to update the number only and the GB should stay.

Note: there is a comma after each variable assignments like below:

```
initParams=undo_tablespace=UNDOTBS1,sga_target=3GB,db_block_size=8192BYTES,nls_language=AMERICAN,dispatchers=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(SERVICE=I00SBXSBXXDB),diagnostic_dest={ORACLE_BASE},control_files=("{ORACLE_BASE}/oradata/{DB_UNIQUE_NAME}/control01.ctl","/u02/fast_recovery_area/{DB_UNIQUE_NAME}/control02.ctl"), remote_login_passwordfile=EXCLUSIVE,audit_file_dest=ORACLE_BASE}/admin/{DB_UNIQUE_NAME}/adump,processes=320,pga_aggregate_target=2GB,nls_territory=AMERICA,local_listener=LISTENER_I00SBX,db_recovery_file_dest_size=50GB,open_cursors=300,log_archive_format=%t_%s_%r.arc,db_domain=TEST.COM,compatible=19.0.0,db_name=I00SBX,db_recovery_file_dest=/u03/fast_recovery_area/{DB_UNIQUE_NAME},audit_trail=db
```

I tried the following sed code keeping in mind the comma separated values but it is not updating the number to user input value. Not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
sed -i 's/\(sga_target\)=[^,]*\1="${sga_target}/GB"/g' dbca2.rsp
```

Comment: Which kind of file it is? Is it XML?

Comment: it is a database response file, I am able to replace many other values but can't seem to get this variable replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Using Perl's one-liner, this is `sed` on steroids:

```
perl -i -spe 's/\b(sga_target=)\d+GB\b/$1$sga_target/' -- -sga_target=12GB file
```

##### Using `sed`:

```
sga_target=12GB
sed -i -E "s/\b(sga_target=)[[:digit:]]+GB\b/\1$sga_target/" file
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `sga_target=` | 'sga_target=' |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `[[:digit:]]+` | any character of: digits (like \d) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `GB` | 'GB' |
| `\b` | the boundary anchor between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char anchor |

Comment: it seems it is not adding the GB back for some reason. Only the numbers remain after the update.

Comment: You need to add GB in the variable. Or adapt a bit.

Comment: This will automatically add GB:  sed -i -E "s/\b(sga_target=)[[:digit:]]+GB\b/\1$sga_target\GB/"